# Confused about parsing method

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, text, split

I'm trying to write a class that parses a text file, stores the information in an array based on what year the employee joined, and create an employee, salesman, or executive object based on each line. My professor gave us this line to parse the year

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        int year = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0,4));
        Employee e = getEmployee(line);
    }
```

And this method to parse the rest of the document

```
 public static Employee getEmployee(String line)
{
    Employee e= new Employee()
    String[] splitWithComma = line.split(",");
    String first = splitWithComma[0];
    String[] firstSplit = first.split(" ");
    String second = splitWithComma[1];
    String[] secondSplit = second.split(" ");
    String third = splitWithComma[2];
    String[] thirdSplit = third.split(" ");
    String fourth = splitWithComma[3];
    String[] fourthSplit = fourth.split(" ");
    String fifth=splitWithComma[4];
    String[] fifthSplit = fifth.split(" ");


}
```

I'm confused about how I should initialize the Employee object in the getEmployee class, and if I need to parse any my doubles in the while method, and how to do that

Here's my text file

```
2014, Employee, John Baker, 15000
2014, Salesman, Amanda Stein, 30000, 1100000
2014, Executive, Jessica Kettner, 53
2015, Employee,Zach Edwards, 20000
2015, Salesman,Shelby Douglas, 45000, 2345
2015, Executive, Corey Matthews, 67000, 48
```

My employee class

```
import java.util.*;

public class Employee 
{
private String name;
private double monthlySalary;

public Employee(String name, double monthlySalary)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.monthlySalary=monthlySalary;
}



public String getName() {
    return name;
}



public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}



public double getMonthlySalary() {
    return monthlySalary;
}



public void setMonthlySalary(int MonthlySalary)
{

}



public double annualSalary()
{
    return monthlySalary*12;
}







public String toString()
{
    String str;
    str="Name: "+name;
    str+="\nMonthly Salary: "+monthlySalary;
    return str;
}
}
```

And my driver

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class employeeDriver
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String line;
    String input;
    Scanner readInput=null;
    Scanner readFile = null;
    BufferedReader br=null;

    try
    {
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("tester.txt"));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("The file can't be opened");
        System.exit(0);
    }


try
{   
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        int year = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0,4));
        Employee e = getEmployee(line);
    }

}

catch (IOException ioe)
{
    System.out.println("Can't read file");
}
finally
{
    System.exit(0);
}

}


public static Employee getEmployee(String line)
{
    Employee e= new Employee()
    String[] splitWithComma = line.split(",");
    String first = splitWithComma[0];
    String[] firstSplit = first.split(" ");
    String second = splitWithComma[1];
    String[] secondSplit = second.split(" ");
    String third = splitWithComma[2];
    String[] thirdSplit = third.split(" ");
    String fourth = splitWithComma[3];
    String[] fourthSplit = fourth.split(" ");
    String fifth=splitWithComma[4];
    String[] fifthSplit = fifth.split(" ");


} 
}
```

Comment: Read the help for [`string.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), it might help...

Comment: I understand how split works, I'm just unsure about how the getEmployee method will parse the rest of the text file, and how to store it in my Employee object

Comment: `getEmployee` parses only one line at a time; each line of the text file is read and then parsed with it. Also, my comment regarding the help was because the records are comma-separated, not space-separated, so looking at the code you posted I had the impression that it was not clear how it works.

Comment: OK, I edited it so that it's space seperated. The only thing that has a comma is the name of the employee. What line in getEmployee is     String[] splitWithComma = line.split(","); applied?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, the Employee constructor is taking a String and a double as input, so when you create the new Employee-object you must (unless you make another constructor) supply those values, like this:

```
Employee e = new Employee("John Baker", 15000);
```

For the parsing bit, it looks like the getEmployee method is expected handle that, so that all you put in your while loop is this

```
Employee e = getEmployee(line);
```

The getEmployee method is incomplete though. Since you need the name and salary already when you create the Employee object, you should do the parsing first and then create the object.

About parsing doubles, there is a Double.parseDouble(String) method, but it seems that in your text file the salaries are formatted as integers anyway, and if you try to do something like

```
int salary = Integer.parseInt(salaryStr);
Employee e = new Employee("John Baker", salary);
```

then Java should cast the integer to a double automatically. Whether the salary should be a double or int in the class itself is another story.

Comment: OK, so the information in getEmployee handles the information. Am I missing anymore information for parsing, and if not, how would I declare it for employee? Would I pass three and four, since they have the employee name and salary? And what would I do for my Salesman and Executive subclases?

Comment: It all depends on what your requirements are for the Employee class to begin with. It seems like you're doing a lot of unnecessary splits, all you need is really in the first "splitWithComma" string. To reflect the different types of employees it might be appropriate to use an Employee superclass, and then have RegularEmployee, Salesman and Executive inherit from that.